# how to create different view for last visible cell of tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to show last visible cell with different background color (say green).
I am using this code, It works good until I scroll up/down. When I scroll up/down it gives many cell with green background. (I guess this happening due to "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier").
Can anyone help me out where I am doing wrong or what is the best way of doing this.

```
NSArray* indexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
if (indexPath.row==[indexPaths count]-1)
{
    UIView *v=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    v.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    cell.backgroundView=v;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you shouldn't be allocating anything in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - it is bad for performance. You should only be configuring views and controls that already exist for every cell. Because cells are reused, your cell that you add a background view to will get re-used too... and its background view.

In your case, you probably just want to set:

```
if (lastCell)
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
else
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; //or whatever color
```

`contentView` is already a view every `UITableViewCell` has for free, so just use that for background color. Apple probably intended it to be used for this case, amongst others.

Answer (score 0):

You should nil the background view before the test.

```
cell.backgroundView = nil;

if (indexPath.row==[indexPaths count]-1)
{
    UIView *v=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    v.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    cell.backgroundView=v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.row==[yourtableviewarray count]-1)
    {
        UIView *v=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
        v.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        cell.backgroundView=v;
    }

}
```

Comment: my question is for visible last cell not for the last cell of table view.